# VS Code: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: visual-studio-code, javafx

I am trying to run my project: `App.java` but this error pops up in VS Code terminal:

> JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I have actually completed this project: `App.java` in a year ago and I was able to run `App.java` smoothly without this error during that time. Since then, I have not run `App.java` for about 11 months and now I would like to run `App.java` again. However, this time, I got this error.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Java/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

Environment Variables (User Variable):
Variable Name: `JAVA_HOME`
Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1`

p.s. I have already set up all these a year ago when I complete this project and `App.java` was able to run without this error. I didn't change any part of the code including `settings.json` and `launch.json`. I really have no idea why this error pops up after a year when I want to run `App.java` again.

I have tried to restart my VS Code, run VS Code in Administrator Mode, uninstall and reinstall Extension Pack for Java in VS Code, disable and enable again all the extensions I have used in VS Code, followed all the other guides asked by other user who also faced this issue. Sadly, I still get this error.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode